# Sql Server Management Studio - saving query results to an insert script

Tags: sql-server

Is there an easy way to create an insert statement from a result list.  I Have to import 1000's of rows and it's preferable to have it as an insert() statement rather than an excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic SQL to generate insert statements instead of getting results.

From query

```
select columnname from mytable
```

You can generate insert statements

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''

select @sql = @sql + N'insert into mytable(columnname) values (' + columnname + N'); ' from mytable

print @sql
```